# How to refresh a page via Back Button

Tags: jquery-mobile, dojo, xpages

I'm completely new to jQuery Mobile and just trying to get a feel for how it might to work in my environment.

One Page 1 I'm displaying values that come down from the server.  What I want to do is go to Page2 to set the values and then pressing "Back" have page 1 show the updated values.

Currently when I hit back, it's showing the original values and I need to do a manual partial or full refresh to get them updated.

How can I tell jQuery Mobile to auto refresh a page on hitting the back button?  I'm using data-rel="back".

I guess I'm looking to see if there's a universal setting for this or something.  Similar to  $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; which I needed to turn on in my environment to get things working.

Thanks

UPDATE:
I've added some code here per request. Not sure it will really help.  But here's what's going on.  I'm trying to use jQuery Mobile in the context of an IBM XPages application.  XPages is basically Java Server Faces but it has Dojo 1.8.1 built into it do to certain things like a Partial Refresh of a Div automatically.  So for instance on a button I can write server side code - int a Java Managed Bean, get a result, and have it partial refresh a div on the webpage.  Cool stuff. But the problem I GUESS is conflicts between jQuery Mobile and the build in Dojo that makes those things work.  I don't want to use the mobile portion of Dojo because jQuery seems so much better.

Anyway - I got jQuery Mobile to work by making sure it loaded BEFORE the dojo pieces loaded.  The other way around it wouldn't work at all.  I'd like to work with individual pages rather then virtual pages in one.

I'm not sure if I care about much caching really as the pages will almost always be changing.  I'm working on an inventory application with iPads and barcode scanners.  So for instance on page1 I scan an item.  Then I might move to page 2 to let the user do something with the item, on hitting the back button I want page 1 to refresh so it's updated with any new information

Thanks for any advice!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/xsp/.ibmxspres/.mini/css/@Da&amp;@Ib&amp;2Tfxsp.css&amp;2TfxspLTR.css&amp;2TfxspSF.css.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.8.1/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="locale: 'en-us'"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/xsp/.ibmxspres/.mini/dojo/.en-us/@Iq.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">dojo.require('ibm.xsp.widget.layout.xspClientDojo')</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jqm.nsf/themes/czarnowskiMobile.min.css">
</head>
<body class="xspView tundra">
<form id="view:_id1" method="post" action="/jqm.nsf/home.xsp" class="xspForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b">
<div data-role="header">
<h1><span id="view:_id1:_id2:computedField1" class="xspTextComputedField">Scanner</span></h1></div>
<div data-role="content">
<div id="view:_id1:_id2:callback3">
<ul data-role="listview"><li><a id="view:_id1:_id2:callback3:link2" href="/jqm.nsf/menuFacility.xsp" class="xspLink">Facility Menu</a></li><li><a id="view:_id1:_id2:callback3:link3" href="/jqm.nsf/menuShow.xsp" class="xspLink">Show Menu</a></li></ul><br><div id="view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:timePanel">
<table><tr><td><span id="view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:label1" class="xspTextLabel">viewScope</span></td>
<td><span id="view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:computedField1" class="xspTextComputedField"></span></td>
<td><button class="xspButtonCommand" type="button" name="view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:button1" id="view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:button1" data-role="none">Update</button></td>
<td><button class="xspButtonCommand" type="button" name="view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:button3" id="view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:button3" data-role="none">Clear</button></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><span id="view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:label2" class="xspTextLabel">sessionScope</span></td>
<td><span id="view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:computedField2" class="xspTextComputedField"></span></td>
<td><button class="xspButtonCommand" type="button" name="view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:button2" id="view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:button2" data-role="none">Update</button></td>
<td><button class="xspButtonCommand" type="button" name="view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:button4" id="view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:button4" data-role="none">Clear</button></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Current Time</td>
<td><span id="view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:computedField3" class="xspTextComputedField">7:39:40 PM</span></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><button class="xspButtonCommand" type="button" name="view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:button5" id="view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:button5" data-role="none">Partial Refresh</button></td>
<td><button class="xspButtonCommand" type="button" name="view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:button6" id="view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:button6" data-role="none">Full Refresh</button></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
<div id="view:_id1:_id2:callback2">
Footer Test</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>  $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
          $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;</script>
<input type="hidden" name="$$viewid" id="view:_id1__VUID" value="!dgljtbhtgw!">
<input type="hidden" name="$$xspsubmitid">
<input type="hidden" name="$$xspexecid">
<input type="hidden" name="$$xspsubmitvalue">
<input type="hidden" name="$$xspsubmitscroll">
<input type="hidden" name="view:_id1" value="view:_id1"></form>
<script type="text/javascript">

XSP.addOnLoad(function() {
XSP.attachPartial("view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:eventHandler1", "view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:button1", null, "onclick", function(){}, 2, "view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:timePanel");
XSP.attachPartial("view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:eventHandler3", "view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:button3", null, "onclick", function(){}, 2, "view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:timePanel");
XSP.attachPartial("view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:eventHandler2", "view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:button2", null, "onclick", function(){}, 2, "view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:timePanel");
XSP.attachPartial("view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:eventHandler4", "view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:button4", null, "onclick", function(){}, 2, "view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:timePanel");
XSP.attachPartial("view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:_id32", "view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:button5", null, "onclick", function(){}, 2, "view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:timePanel");
XSP.attachEvent("view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:_id34", "view:_id1:_id2:callback3:_id12:button6", "onclick", null, true, 2);
}); 

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: rel="external" on anchors forces a full page refresh. However, could you show us some code so that we will make it work with Ajax? Ajax transitions are important for the performance of your app. I wouldn't recommend disabling it.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure where to put rel="external" since it's just for the back button.  All the pages should be discrete pages on the same server - I'm trying to avoid "virtual pages".